# CentOS 7 FTP unable to retrieve directory list

Tags: centos, ftp, centos7

So I recently installed my DirectAdmin license on my server which is running centOS 7 but now I am getting stuck with connetcing to my FTP server.

I have done the following commands to open my FTP ports:

```
 firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=20-1023/tcp --permanent
 firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=50000-50500/tcp --permanent
```

As of what I read this should be opening the port range 20 to 1023 which also should be the correct ports for this. Now once I try to connect to an account I get the following messages in FileZilla

```
Status: Resolving address of domain.ext
Status: Connecting to IP:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (IP)
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I'm wondering if I need to open any more ports for this to work?

Comment: You don't mention that you actually restricted your FTP server (and restarted after changing the configuration) to only use ports in the range `50000-50500` for passive connections....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is selinux enabled?  If so, you may have to have some options set.  You can check in your audit logs, say grep for AVC, or do a quick test with setenforce 0, and see if it works.  If it does after that, then it is selinux, otherwise you would need to check other options.

Comment: It indeed seemed to be with selinux.